# Extending std::unordered_set<> for use with std::stack<>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stack, unordered-set

My problem: I want to use `std::stack<std::pair<int,int>, std::unordered_set<std::pair<int,int>>`

or `std::stack<coords, std::unordered_set<coords>>` for short

I would like to know if it is possible to extend `std::unordered_set<>` such that it will function with no issues inside of `std::stack<>`.
Beyond that I would like to know if it is even worth the effort, without divulging the actual end use. I just mean for the benefits of using an unordered_set would it be more efficient to design my own template with the necessary methods rather than extend the existing unordered_set to meet requirements?

Edit: Normally I would delete a negative question, but I feel as though this may end up being helpful to some other poor soul who has misunderstood the std::unordered_set. Then again I am not dead yet, so I may very well delete this yet.

Edit 2: The answer from AndreyT below helped for figuring out why `std::stack<std::pair<int,int>, std::unordered_set<std::pair<int,int>>` can't be a thing. I switch to jxh's answer because it essentially implemented one and is close to what I ended up using.

Comment: i think it should be unordered_set<int,int> instead of unordered_set<std::pair<int,int>>

Comment: @STNYU I don't think so.. the key is the value for an unordered_set. Also I am storing data which is std::pair<int,int> this is how I store it everywhere else, I like to be consistent.

Comment: Just how do you expect this to work? `std::stack` is a container ordered by insertion time. `std::unordered_set` is a container ordered by a hash function. Could you describe what you actually want to achieve (in terms of performance, or example)?

Comment: I have likely misunderstood the way in which an unordered_set stores and looks up its data. I was under the impression that the data stayed unordered, much like a stack, and that it merely used the hash table for lookups.

Comment: No, the elements in an `unordered_set` do not stay ordered. The order is purely arbitrary and can change on any insertion that triggers a rehash e.g. if the bucket count is 10 and element A has hash code 45 and element B has hash code 675 then they will both be in the same bucket (45%10 == 675%10), but if the bucket count changes to 11 they will be moved to different buckets (45%11 != 675%11)

Comment: The whole point of `unordered_xxx` containers is O(1) lookup to arbitrary members anywhere in the container and O(1) insertion anywhere in the container. The whole point of `std::stack` is that you only access it at one end. Your question is like asking if you can adapt a shelf for use as a conveyor belt. If you tried hard enough maybe you could, but it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Okay, that clears up all my misunderstandings. Thank you for your additional input, wish I could give you some points somehow

Comment: please try reading some documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: @TemplateRex Please try reviewing the checkmark below. Problem solved bud.

Comment: @JoshC I meant: please try and read standard documentation before asking such questions.

Comment: @TemplateRex I meant: if you read everything here you might get the impression that I did and misunderstood what I read...

Comment: And I thought you switched because of the "Love Shack" parody :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already explained in a different answer, an unordered set is not a suitable container for the stack interface, as the supplied container is supposed to provide the ordering semantics. An unordered set does not provide ordering semantics, as indicated by its name.

It seems that what you want is a LIFO data structure, but you want to be able to find a particular element in that data structure in O(1), and manipulate it (I guess find and remove it).

The best you can probably do is your own data structure that has a stack using a list, and an unordered map of coordinates to iterators into that list.

```
class MyFunkyStack {
    std::list<coord> list_;
    std::stack<coord, std::list<coord>> stack_;
    std::unordered_map<coord, std::list<coord>::iterator> map_;
    //...

    MyFunkyStack () : list_(), stack_(list_), map_() {}

    coord top () const { return stack_.top(); }

    void push (coord c) {
        stack_.push(c);
        map_[c] = list_.end() - 1;
    }

    void pop () { erase(top()); }

    void erase (coord c) {
        std::unordered_map<coord, std::list<coord>::iterator>::iterator i;
        if ((i = map_.find(c)) == map_.end()) return;
        list_.erase(i->second);
        map_.erase(i);
    }

    //...

};
```

With apologies to the B-52's:

<sup><sub>If you see an old log line buried in the archived syslog that says: /
"15 MB in the Hash Stack" /
Hash Stack, yeah, yeah //
I'm downloading an open source project. /
Looking for the hash-ay able-tay! /
Compile the hash table today. //
I got me a tar-ball, it's too big for e-mail. /
And we're downloading it for my Hash Stack. //
I got me a compiler, it optimizes plenty, /
So hurry up and get your build box ready! //
The Hash Stack is a little weird container that we made together. /
Hash Stack, baby (a Hash Stack baby!) //
Hash Stack, baby, Hash Stack! /
Hash Stack, baby, Hash Stack! //
(Hash, baby, that's where it's at.) /
(Hash, baby, that's where it's at.) //
License (ooh!) is open source dudes! /
Cause sharing's cool for the Hash Stack. //
It's just a small class, with just a few fields. /
It's a weird funky stack, and kind of a hack. //
Doesn't need destructor. /
Doesn't need assignment. /
Doesn't need move or copy. /
Doesn't need assignment. //
The Hash Stack is a little weird container that we made together. /
Hash Stack, baby (a Hash Stack baby!) //
(Hash, baby, that's where it's at.) /
(Hash, baby, that's where it's at.) //
Typing and a-mousing, /
Thinking and a-coding, /
Wearing next to nothing, /
Because I'm working at home (yeah). //
The Hash Stack compiles! /
The Hash Stack compiles! //
The Hash Stack compiles, /
While other stacks are still just /
Arrays, and arrays, and arrays, and arrays! //
Other stacks just pushing, other stacks just popping, baby! /
Last ones queued up are the first ones to get out. //
Other stacks just pushing, other stacks just popping, baby! /
A weird funky stack! /
A weird funky stack! //
While I compile (dependencies are stale), I send an e-mail! //
I launch a new "make", reniced at -20, /
So hurry up, and get your build box ready! //
The Hash Stack is a little weird container that we made together. /
Hash Stack, baby (a Hash Stack baby!) //
Hash Stack, baby, Hash Stack! /
Hash Stack, baby, Hash Stack! //
(Hash, baby, that's where it's at, yeah.) /
(Hash, baby, that's where it's at.) //
Test, test, test, still no core, baby. /
Try a few more cases, baby /
Test, test, test, still no core, baby. /
What's your test plan? //
Test, test, test, still no core, baby. /
Try a few more cases, sugar /
Test, test, test, still no core, baby. /
What's your test plan? //
Test, test, test, still no core, baby. /
                  (Try a few more cases.) /
Test, test, test, still no core, baby. //
Test, test! (Got a core, baby!) /
Test, test! (Got a core!) /
Test, test! (Got a core, baby!) /
Test, test! //
You did what? /
Reproduced, blocker! //
Hash Stack, baby, Hash Stack! /
(Hash, baby, that's where it's at, yeah.) /
(Hash, baby, that's where it's at.) //
Hash, baby, Hash Stack! /
Typing and a-mousing, /
Thinking and a-coding, /
On the Hash Stack.</sub></sup>

Comment: Similar, sort of, but not exactly what I wanted this for. I will definitely give this some consideration though, it may provide me what I need.

Comment: shouldn't the stack in your funkystack be a stack of iterators?

Comment: The idea is you can write a routine to remove a coordinate by searching the `map_`, and then erasing the map entry and the list entry. This will make it disappear from the stack as well.

Comment: Oh I missed the stack constructor, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

`std::stack` is by intent is a data structure ordered in accordance to LIFO principle. Within that intent, it places the data into the underlying container in certain order and expects that container to maintain that order. It is not possible to use as an underlying container any container that would change the ordering on its own accord. The eliminates any *unordered* data structure or a data structure ordered in accordance with some other principle.

However, that logic applies only if you want to maintain the above intent of `std::stack`, i.e. use it to implement a stack, literally.

If you don't care what you get in the end (in the most extreme case, if you just want your code to "compile"), then you can see `std::stack` as a "thin" abstract interface adaptor that does nothing more than just adapts the interface of some underlying class. From that point of view, you can use absolutely anything as an underlying "container", as long as it satisfies the required interface specification. As far as I remember, that includes availability of `empty`, `size`, `back`, `push_back`, `pop_back` methods and, possibly, some typedefs.

`unordered_set`, as you probably already noticed, does not satisfy the required interface specification. You can formally "extend" it just "to make it compile", but I don't see how you can possibly make it work for a true stack.

Comment: So std::stack isn't able to know what the last item was unless that item is kept specifically on whichever end of the underlying container it is expected on? Furthermore an unordered set doesn't know when an item was added to it relative to another item it has stored??

Comment: `std::stack` maintains **no state** at all. All it does is _adapt_ an existing container's interface, **hiding** some of its members (and renaming others) so you can only insert and erase at the end of the container. An underlying container which doesn't have an "end" is **impossible** to use with `std::stack` because it doesn't even provide the `push_back` and `pop_back` member functions.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Your response seems to imply an answer to my second question. Which I have suspected since receiving input on this problem. std::unordered_set doesn't maintain any form of information about when something was added? I figured, originally, that the iterators would be kept in order of when things were added. I would like to know what I suspect is true or false explicitly though.

Comment: See my comment on your question above. There is an order, but its arbitrary and can change at any time. The clue is in the name "unordered"